# limit of a radical function

Tags: limits, radicals

I want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n} = 0$ where $a_{n}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$
$$
a_{n}={\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\over1}\bullet{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\over\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
\\
a_{n}={1\over\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$
Now I know the denominator gets infinitly large so it will go to zero but I cant seem to show that it does go to infinity. Maybe...
$$
{1\over\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}>{1\over\sqrt{n}}
$$
That root is confusing me, thank you.

Comment: Is the question: Why $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ goes to infinity when $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @MrSelberg Sort of.

Answer (score 2):

the correct inequality is:
$$\frac {1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
So, as $n\to\infty$ we have $\frac {1}{\sqrt{n}}\to0$, or $\frac {1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\to0$

Comment: Ahhhhh yes, not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove that for any $U \in \Bbb{R}$ there is an $n \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $ \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n} > U$ then your job is done.

The reason being $ \sqrt{n+1}+ \sqrt{n} $ is a strictly increasing function, so if you find a single n that's big enough every value after that will also be bigger. Furthermore by showing there isn't A single real number U that bounds the thing, and it's increasing, we conclude it tends to infinity.